# count repeated value in table field

Tags: php, mysql

how i can count the  repeated value in any field of mysql db's table.

**Example:**

```
    id name
    1  aaa
    2  aaa
    3  ttt
    4  ccc
    5  ttt
    6  ccc
    7  aaa
    8  zzz
```

How i can get how many times value is repeated in table like.

```
    aaa =3 times in table
    ttt =2 times in table
    ccc =2 times in table
    zzz =1 times in table
```

I think it possible with count of the mysql but how to use it i dont know any one can help ?please answer ma question thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below query to get count of each name

```
select name, count(name)
from your_table
group by name
```

OR
to get count of specific name

```
select name, count(name)
from your_table
where name = "aaa"
group by name
```

Comment: here in name i want to count some specific value like how many times aaa is repeated in name field in ma table.

Comment: use where clause for specific name OR In resulting array you will get count for each name.

Comment: what you tried can you post your query along with your question?

Answer (score 5):

You need to group by your `name` column and then you can use an aggregate function like `count()` on that group

```
select name, count(id)
from your_table
group by name
```

Comment: Isnt grouping by the id going to produce the same result set as its unique? Does he not have to group by name and then do a count? :S